# Same strings in different contexts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, localization, users-page, russian-stackoverflow

Seems the string [`$__count$ days`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263458?key=151e08c767c86417dff98389b214c673) is used for days count at least in 2 different contexts:

1. [New users page:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers)

   > [image: newUsers]
2. [User profile page:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227835/andrew-evt)

   > [image: profile]

In Russian the language needs to distinguish these two grammar cases.

Perhaps there are another use cases where identical strings are used in different contexts, so need to use different strings for localization purpose.

Comment: To possible close voters: although this seems to only pertain to a specific site, any changes made to the localization impact all sites network wide. In that sense it is not off-topic here on MSE.

Comment: @AdamLear why you replaced [meta-tag:bug] to [meta-tag:feature-request]? I think in terms of [meta-tag:localization] my post is about bug, not a feature request.

Comment: @alexolut The difference is minor, but this isn't a bug in the strictest sense. This is literally a feature that's missing from our localization engine, not just a matter of fixing up how strings are expressed in code or something on a similarly smaller scale.

Comment: @AdamLear: I'd argue that the difference it _not_ minor for native speakers. It's like seeing "22 day" instead of "days". If this were in English localization, would you perceive it as a missing feature or a bug?

Comment: @Vlad Adam meant the difference between [tag:bug] and [tag:feature-request] was minor, not the wording itself. i.e, this question is asking to add a feature that doesn’t exist, rather than asking to fix something that isn’t working as intended.

Comment: @Cai according to the good localization for already supported languages it is a bug. Like plurals issues in English, as Vlad said.